# Asserts in loop

Tags: java, selenium

On site: http://live.guru99.com/index.php/mobile.html
I want to check prices of all available products, More precisely: checking equality price on mobile.html under image, and on product details after click on image.

Which way is the best to do that operation?
I'm just started with checking price of first product

```
  String price1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".price")).getText();
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".product-image")).click();
  String price2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".price")).getText();
  Assert.assertTrue(price1.equals(price2));
```

Comment: So what is your question here or where are you stuck?

Comment: Assuming the code you posted above is the algorithm for checking a single product's price, it seems like a good approach would be to wrap up the code in a method, then invoke it three times in a for/while loop.
I'd suggest being careful with this approach, since you would be dependent on the changed state of the driver instance, which will iterate on your HTML elements. I would personally prefer to get an (ordered) list of elements first, then iterate on it using an assertion method.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.get("http://live.guru99.com/index.php/mobile.html");

List<WebElement> phones = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".products-grid > li"));
int size = phones.size();

for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {

   WebElement phone = phones.get(i);

   // read prices from list page
   StringBuffer exp_prices = new StringBuffer();
   // for some phone, there are two price, one is old, another is new price
   List<WebElement> eles = phone.findElements(By.cssSelector(".price-box .price"));
   for(WebElement ele:eles) {
      exp_prices.append(ele.getText().trim() + ",");
   }

   // click phone image enter detail page
   phone.findElement(By.cssSelector(".product-image")).click();

   // read prices from detail page
   StringBuffer act_prices = new StringBuffer();
   List<WebElement> eles2 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".product-view .price-info .price"));
   for(WebElement ele:eles2) {
      act_prices.append(ele.getText().trim() + ",");
   }

   // check prices
   Assert.assertEquals(exp_prices.toString(), act_prices.toString());

   // history back to detail page
   driver.navigate().back();

   // find phones on list page again to avoid `StateReferenceException`
   phones = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".products-grid > li"));
}
```